# ImportError: No module named nnutils.rnn

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I'm working with RNN. I dealing with testing data and training data. Currently in my system I have kinetic ROS version and default version of Python is 2.7.12. Also Ubuntu version is 16.04. I have `rnn.py` file inside the `nnunits` folder.

I'm running from another `rnntraintest.py` file by importing methods from `rnn.py` files.

This is my import libraries code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import keras
import os
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import loadmat, savemat
import matplotlib as mpl

from nnutils.rnn import RNNOfflineData, buildRNN, testRNN

mpl.use('TkAgg')  # or whatever other backend that you want
if mpl:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

After source the my workspace and run  the `rnntraintest.py` file but after that I'm getting this error:

```
rosrun rnn_test01 rnntraintest.py 

Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/larz/catkin_chanaka/src/rnn_test01/scripts/example_rnn/rnntraintest.py", line 16, in <module>

    from nnutils.rnn import RNNOfflineData#, buildRNN, testRNN
ImportError: No module named nnutils.rnn
```

Is it a problem with the version of Python I used or ROS version or anything else? And how can I solve it?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python` will use whatever Python executable appears first in a user's `$PATH`. It seems plausible that the version of Python being referenced isn't the version you have `nnutils.rnn` installed for. At a guess, one (partial) solution might be to run `which python` then run `python -m pip freeze` against each path returned to figure out where `nnutils.rnn` was actually installed.